# Undefined Reference to 'mysql_get_client_info' Eclipse Centos 6

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I am trying to compile the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>


int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, Eclipse is giving the following error messaage:

Building target: TestConsole4
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/usr/include -L/usr/include/mysql -o "TestConsole4"  ./src/TestConsole4.o
./src/TestConsole4.o: In function `main':
/home/hearme/workspace/TestConsole4/Debug/../src/TestConsole4.c:19: undefined reference to`mysql_get_client_info'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestConsole4] Error 1

I have been going around in circles trying to fix this, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the MySQL reference manual:

"MySQL clients must be linked using the -lmysqlclient -lz options in the link command. You may also need to specify a -L option to tell the linker where to find the library. For example, if the library is installed in /usr/local/mysql/lib, use these options in the link command:

-L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz"

Comment: OK,

So this is a list of files in /usr/lib64/mysql/ folder:

libmysqlclient.so (link to libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0)
libmysqlclient.so.16 (link to link to libmysqllcient.so.16.0.0)
libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0

I presume I need to link to libmysqclient.so, however, when I try to do this in Eclipse, I receive the message:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmysqlclient.so

Here is what the Linker is invoking:

gcc -L/usr/lib64/mysql/ -o "TestConsole4"  ./src/TestConsole4.o   -llibmysqlclient.so -lz

Comment: RESOLVED: Although, "-lmysqlclient -lz" was to be added

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments to the linker is significant. Use mysql-config after listing the files that need it. The linker will see that objectfile.o needs mysql_init and look in libraries listed after it for the symbol. If the libraries were listed earlier in the arguments they won't be searched again.
my c code:

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

compiling command eg(any one):
gcc -o sqlversion.o sqlversion.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
or gcc -o sqlversion.o sqlversion.c -lmysqlclient
or gcc -o sqlversion.o sqlversion.c -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz -lm -ldl -lssl -lmysqlclient

running eg: ./sqlversion.o

my output:MySQL client version: 8.0.26

Here usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is the path to the libmysqlclient.a library that gets installed while installing the mysql.
you can find he path using command: find /usr/ -name 'libmysqlclient.a'